# empty modules.dep for new kernel compilation

Tags: shell-script, linux-kernel, compiling, kernel-modules, modprobe

i've got empty `modules.dep` file after compiling new kernel from source

after kernel compile, and then kernel module compile and then `make modules_install` to modules directory, i checked `modules.dep` file inside destination modules directory is empty, and then i ran this command

`depmod -a -b <kernel-modules-dest-dir> -e -F <kernel-source-directory>/System.map -n -v 4.7.0`

and the result was :

```
# Aliases extracted from modules themselves.
# Soft dependencies extracted from modules themselves.
# Aliases for symbols, used by symbol_request().
# Device nodes to trigger on-demand module loading.
```

i'am compiling kernel 4.7.0 using host with version 4.4.x (ubuntu 16.04), there are a lot of .ko files inside `<kernel-modules-dest-dir>` but somehow depmod don't see any compiled loadable kernel modules

these are roughly the command script i ran :

`cp ../../kernel-config ./.config-x86_64
make mrproper
make menuconfig
make -j8
make bzImage
cp arch/x86/boot/bzImage ../../vmlinuz
mkdir -p ../../kernel-modules
make modules
make modules_install INSTALL_MOD_PATH=../../kernel-modules`

**is they anything wrong in my compilation step ?**

Answer (score 1):

The same happened to me (modules_install compressed each module),
and after I disabled in menuconfig:
Enable loadable module support -> Compress modules on installation,
depmod successfully built modules.dep
  Other possibility is to inform depmod if modules are compressed, by using a flag.

Kind regards